# Is there a term for when you are no longer an expat?

Tags: terminology

If an expat moves back to his home country, he is no longer an expat. Is there a term for the process of moving back? What is someone who is no longer an expat called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's [repatriation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repatriation) for the process, but I associate that term with involuntary repatriation, as it's something that is done *to or for you*.

Supposedly there's the related noun [repatriate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repatriate) to refer to the individual, but I haven't actually heard it used before.

Comment: "Repatriation" is used extensively in Israel with regards to the immigration based on the Right of Return.

Comment: @littleadv: In Israel the terms are in Hebrew...

Answer (score 3):

A not-very-exciting but certainly accurate and self-explanatory term might be "returnee"?